# Why might one load a library more than once in an R script?

Tags: r

I am trying to understand some code well enough that I can create the necessary files to make it run it for a client. I thought it was odd that it loads a library within a loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(ids) ){
    library(limma)

    # About 80 lines of code

}
```

Is there any likely reason that someone would want to reload the same library multiple times? I thought that libraries didn't **do** anything besides provide functions.

I searched the [`limma` user guide](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/limma/man/limma.pdf) for the keywords "library" and "load" and didn't find anything obvious.

I would almost think this were an accident if it weren't the very first line in the loop.

Comment: This does look like bad programming style. Does moving it out of the loop break the code?

Comment: In my opinion it is not necessary.

Comment: The only context I can think of is if a library took up a large amount of memory and was unloaded partway through the loop.  I think there's an issue if someone needs to load an entire library that large in such a manner, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a mistake.  Change the `library` call to `library(limma, verbose=TRUE)` and you'll see that only the first call actually does anything (something is returned *invisibly*, but they're not using it because it's not being assigned).

For example:

```
> pkgs <- library(base, verbose=TRUE)
Warning message:
In library(base, verbose = TRUE) :
  package ‘base’ already present in search()
> pkgs
# [1] "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets" 
# [6] "setwidth"  "colorout"  "methods"   "base"
```